# Unable to get option name from Django template and pass to view?

Tags: django

The list_users variable contains the username and {{ i.username }} lists all the available users. It's listing all the available users. Now, I want to pass the userid for the username that user selects and get the id to django view.

```
  <select name="select">
     {% for i in list_users %}
        <option value="{{ i.id }}" name="username">{{ i.username }}</option>
     {% endfor %}
     </select>

 if request.POST.get('share'):
            choices = request.POST.getlist('choice')
            person = request.POST.getlist('username')
            for i, j in zip(choices, person):
                start_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
                a = Share(users_id=log_id, files_id=i, shared_user_id=j, shared_date=start_date)
                a.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/uploaded_files/')
```

When I click share nothing is written in Share model. But if I do like this:

```
for i in choices:

    start_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
    a = Share(users_id=log_id, files_id=i, shared_user_id=2,    shared_date=start_date)
    a.save()
```

It's written in Share model. What am I doing wrong with the above code?

Comment: `option` tag has not `name` attribute and what is `choice` in your `POST` data?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was not an Django error at all. It was an simple HTML error. `option tag` doesn't have attribute called `name` but `select` does.

That's why I edited my view to look like this:

```
 person = request.POST.getlist('username')
```

It's working fine now.